# About the URL.createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, django

I am a beginner in django with python, there is a problem i confronting now is that I have a image URL e.g. "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/user_1/XXXX.jpg" and I am trying to use URL.createObjectURL to do a preview, but it is not work. There is the error message:

`companymanage:1278 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.`

```
def companyget(request,username): #view.py
companyname= request.POST['companyname']
selectedcompany = company.objects.get(companyName=companyname)
image_company= Companyimage.objects.filter(CompanyID_id=selectedcompany.UID)
dataset = {
    "DomainName":selectedcompany.DomainName,
    "Address":selectedcompany.companyAddress,
    "Tel":selectedcompany.companyTel,
    "URL":selectedcompany.CompanyURL,
    "Email":selectedcompany.CompanyEmail,
    # "image_company":image_company,
}
imagecount = 0
for image in image_company:
    dataset.update({"image_company"+str(imagecount):image.ImagePath.url})
    dataset.update({"image_company_id"+str(imagecount):image.Seq})
    imagecount += 1

dataset.update({"imagecount":imagecount})

return JsonResponse(dataset, status=200)

 $('#Table_Company tbody').on("click",".dt-edit",function(){  #html with ajax
                $this = $(this);
                var dtRow = $this.parents('tr');
                var tds_company= dtRow.find("td:nth-child(2)");
                var companyname = tds_company.text();
                var curpath = "{{ request.get_full_path }}"

                // alert(companyname)
                // alert(username)

                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: curpath+"/"+"companyget/",
                    data:{
                        companyname:companyname,
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' 
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        // console.log(Object.keys(data).length)
                        for (let i = 0 ; i < data.imagecount;i++){
                            var target_image_URL
                            var target_image_ID
                            for (let j =0; j<Object.keys(data).length;j++){
                                // console.log(Object.keys(data)[j])
                                // console.log(("image_Company"+i.toString()))
                                if(Object.keys(data)[j] == ("image_company"+i.toString())){
                                    // console.log("access")
                                    target_image_URL = Object.values(data)[j]
                                    // console.log( Object.values(data)[j])
                                }
                                if(Object.keys(data)[j] ==("image_company_id"+i.toString())){
                                    target_image_ID = Object.values(data)[j]
                                }
                            }
                            console.log(target_image_URL)
                            console.log(target_image_ID)
                            console.log("{{ request.get_host }}"+target_image_URL)

                            // let blob = fetch("{{ request.get_host }}"+target_image_URL).then(r => r.blob());

                            // console.log(blob)
                            
                            Companyswiper.appendSlide(
                                '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 swiper-slide">'
                                +'<button class="btn btn_close" href="" type="button">X</button>'
                                +'<img class="img-thumbnail" src="'+URL.createObjectURL("{{ request.get_host }}"+target_image_URL)+'" alt="'+target_image_ID+'" /> '
                                +'</div>');
                        }
                        $('#Edit_CompanyName').val(companyname)
                        $('#Edit_DomainName').val(data.DomainName)
                        $('#Edit_Adddress').val(data.Address)
                        $('#Edit_URL').val(data.URL)
                        $('#Edit_Tel').val(data.Tel)
                        $('#Edit_Email').val(data.Email)
                        $('#EditCompany').modal('show')
                    }
                })
```

I already try the image URL in chrome browser and arrived the image successfully. So why i can not use the path in URL.createObjectURL? Is the createObjectURL only accept File, Blob only and i enter the path so case this problem?? Is any solution suggest ???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Ypm.png)

Comment: `createObjectURL(object)` . object must be a File, Blob, or MediaSource object to create an object URL for. [createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: I got it, as I am using the JsonResponse to return the data from view.py to ajax success, it not allow me to send the image directly, and case me to return the image path to try to solve the problem, is any suggestion to pass the image through my case?